# SailsJS : Passing request identifier from policy to controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have defined a custom policy which is invoked for all controllers(works perfectly fine).

Im using winston for logging the requests into file and format goes as:

> [date] - [log level]: [uuid] [log write]

uuid is to differentiate between simultaneous request log writes.

Now while logging the request details using winston, im not able to pass a uuid from my custom policy to controller.

I tried using req.options but i think im doing it wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add anything to `req` .
Just use e.g. `req.uuid = uuid`